# How to delete data between parenthesis

Tags: r

I have a csv file that contains data and information. information is provided between {}. contents of file are in this format.

```
 {information}
 data
 {information}
```

how to delete information and extract only data from file

structure of file

```
 Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  8586 obs. of  1 variable:
$ {: chr  "Data Vers  : 7" "WinDate    : 27.10.2016" "WinTime    : 16:28:31" 
"VecTime    : 265426.631" ...
- attr(*, "spec")=List of 2
..$ cols   :List of 1
.. ..$ {: list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
..$ default: list()
.. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_guess" "collector"
..- attr(*, "class")= chr "col_spec"
```

data looks like this

```
   { 
    properties of data
    }
    x        y      z
    1.2      4.6    5.4
    3.5      2.7    6.8
   {
   properties of data
   }
```

please guide me regarding this

Comment: Could you please use `dput` to show the few lines of data

Comment: sorry i cannot provide data.

Comment: We do not ask for the whole dataset, but for at least one or two lines. If we do not have a slight picture, we can't help! Use head(data) and then just copy paste the first two lines.

Comment: i added sample in question. please check it

Comment: GIVEN the information you have provided at the structure of your file, you have everything mashed up together in one single column. This could mean that there has been an error in the importing of the data.
ALso could you please tell us if the information withing the `{}` changes from row to row? Finally, if you have `x,y,z` in one column would you require them to be in different columns?

Comment: when i load the file.the information within the { } changes from row to row. I have to delete information between { } and i need x,y,z in different columns

Comment: this means that there is 100% surely an error in importing the dataset. If you open the file in excel, all are in a single collumn?

Comment: i did that before. but i have 1000 file and i cannot edit each file

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
library(stringr)
provided_csv<-c("{information}
data_1
{information}","{information}
                data_2
                {information}")
str_match(provided_csv,"\\{(.*?)\\}")[,2]
[1] "information" "information"
```

Comment: I have loaded the file using read.CSV and tried your code. I am getting NA's.  I have to delete information

Comment: I strongly believe that you have to fix the data prior to adding them in R. Make sure your source is providing them to you in correct format!